# Relation between the electric and magnetic fields for an arbitrary electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

When solving the [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Derivation_from_electromagnetic_theory) for electromagnetic waves,
$$
\nabla^{2} \mathbf{E}=\mu_{0} \varepsilon_{0} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{E}}{\partial t^{2}}, \quad \nabla^{2} \mathbf{B}=\mu_{0} \varepsilon_{0} \frac{\partial^{2} \mathbf{B}}{\partial t^{2}}
$$

assuming solutions of the form $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E}_{0} f\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \mathbf{x}-c t\right)$, it arises that the relation between the electric and magnetic fields is
$$
\mathbf{B}=\frac{1}{c} \hat{\mathbf{k}} \times \mathbf{E} \tag{1}
$$

However, $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E}_{0} f\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}} \cdot \mathbf{x}-c t\right)$ is actually a [travelling plane wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave#Traveling_plane_wave), since it has the structure $F(\vec{x}, t)=G(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{n}-c t)$.

Is $(1)$ still a valid relation between electric and magnetic fields for non plane waves?

Comment: As I recall, even non traveling plane waves can be expressed as traveling plane waves using Fourier series if f is square integrable  , so it should hold under those conditions at least.

Comment: The statement is only true in an isotropic medium. In anisotropic medium, the electric field is not perpendicular to wavevector in general.